# Compare values of two or more columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to compare column Wk07Filter with the corresponding columns until Wk13 Filter. The goal is to find if the value is continuously **green**  for more than 3 times. If it is green for more than 3 times then it means that it is available for 4 or more weeks. For e.g. 3rd row is green from Wk10Filter to Wk13Filter and I should write it as available panel

```
Wk7Filter Wk8Filter Wk09Filter Wk10Filter Wk11Filter Wk12Filter Wk13Filter
red         red       purpl      black     black      green      green
yello       yello     yello      yello     green      green      green
red         red       red        green     green      green      green
green       green     green      green     green      green      green
```

[image]

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You miss some columns. Do you know what [**unpivot**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is ?

Comment: Yes I know unpivot. I have attached an image now for the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concat all the columns together

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT id, ',' + Wk7Filter + 
             ',' + Wk8Filter + 
             ',' + Wk09Filter +
             ',' + Wk10Filter +
             ',' + Wk11Filter +
             ',' + Wk12Filter +
             ',' + Wk13Filter + ',' as filter
 FROM YourTable
)
SELECT id 
FROM cte
WHERE filter like '%,green,green,green,green,%'
```

More than 3 green mean have green four times or more.

Comment: Thank you very much Juan. This works perfectly in my code, I could never ever think about it. Yes, I need four green or more.

Comment: I know that was me explaining the code :) .  remember accept the answer if solve your problem. But you should consider normalize your tables.

Comment: There is another issue now, If a green starts on Wk7Filter four times or more then I should return the date as 7 weeks from this Monday i.e 2017-12-11 and if it ends on Wk13Filter than End date as 2018-01-22. It should only pick green when it is four times or more.

Comment: That is a different question and explain the logic more precise with all the cases.

Comment: uid_panel=21460 is green from Wk00Filter to Wk05Filter in the image. In this case there are 4 or more continuous green, therefore I want to return Wk00Filter date as GETDATE() and Wk05 as DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 35). Green represents that panel is available and the dates will represent that it is available from today to five weeks. The tricky part is that I don't have to select anything which is less that four greens. For e.g. green,red,green,red should not be selected whereas green,green,green,green,red should be selected. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry dont understand what you mean :(. But again you should create a new question.